# Noted vs Noted with thanks

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> Noted with thanks
> Noted
> Thanks and noted. 
> Noted and thanks.

I've seen the above variants in work emails. By default, *noted* on its own has no emotional association? If one doesn't use *with thanks* does it feel less welcome?

Comment: 'Noted' is just a brief way of saying 'I have made a note (maybe a mental note) of what you have told me', so if you wish you can add thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you have the gist of this already - using 'thanks' in any form is slightly more polite than without.

Using a single word ('Noted' or 'Done' or similar) to reply to an instructional message is absolutely fine if it is to someone you know well, such as your immediate boss.